# Magento 2 - Issue on override of Multishipping checkout model

Tags: magento2, overrides, magento-2.2.5, multishipping, override-model

With this question I want to go further and to exactly know if it's possible to override:

> vendor/magento/module-multishipping/Model/Checkout/Type/Multishipping.php

so far I've experienced some complications performing this override, I had to override also **PlaceOrderDefaulr**, **PlaceOrderFactory** and **PlaceOrderInferface**

I've added preferences tags in **../etc/di.xml** of my module to include above mentioned classes, but now the error prompted is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
>   Magento\Multishipping\Model\Checkout\Type\Multishipping\State::__construct()
>   must be an instance of
>   Magento\Multishipping\Model\Checkout\Type\Multishipping, instance of
>   **Vendor\MyModule**\Model\Checkout\Type\Multishipping given,
>   called in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
>   on line 111

I've cleared /generated folder and also /var/cache, view_preprocessed, page_cache, session/

and the error is still the same.. as a second parameter in constructor the follwing is called:

> \Magento\Customer\Model\Session

Then used to retrieve logged-in customer information to get addresses, etc.

Any ideas? will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the issue, simply creating an override for

> Magento\Multishipping\Model\Checkout\Type\Multishipping\State

in my module 
and the consequents necessary overrides that were arise after fix that.. just like that.

I've created

> Vendor\MyModule\Model\Checkout\Type\Multishipping\State

And updated namespace and construct to use my module instead the Magento2 one.